# Поиск в строке по шаблону

Tags: поиск, objective-c

Здравствуйте.

У меня такой вопрос по поводу поиска в строке. Допустим, приходит нам длиннющая строка, и там встречается конструкция такого типа:

> text = любой текст [ любой текст | любой текст ] любой текст

При чем в "любой текст" могут быть и любые символы, такие как [ | ]. И тут возникает вопрос КАК вытащить конструкцию "[ любой текст | любой текст ]" гуманным способом. Пытался с помощью предиката

> NSString * string = @" * [ * | * ] *";
>
> NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like %@",string];
>
> [predicate evaluateWithObject:text];

Но он всего лишь говорит, есть такое в строке или нет. А как вытащить, непонятно. Есть ли простой способ или нужно писать длиннющий алгоритм?

Answer (score 1):

Когда ж наконец-то вы все начнете читать справку? Достаточно же просмотреть справку NSString, там же есть спецметод:

```
 NSString *text =@"test text1 [ test text2 | test textт 3] test text 4";
    NSCharacterSet *separatorsSet =[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[|]"];
    NSArray *texts = [text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separatorsSet];
    NSLog(@"texts:\n %@",texts);
```

Comment: А если в "любой текст" встречается знаки | [ ], то вообще непонятно, что брать. Я, наверное, плохо формулирую вопрос. То есть, например, по твоему решению, я имею строку:

"test text1 [ test text2 | test | [ textт 3] test text 4"

а получаю массив всех слов, разделенных этими знаками,

А в ответе мне надо получить только: [ test text2 | test | [ textт 3]

Говорят, что надо регулярными функциями пользоваться, пойду покопаю туда))))

Comment: Естественно, получаешь массив всех строк, ты ж не написал, что у тебя те же самые символы еще и в тексте есть. Тогда да, тогда только регулярками, и то не факт, что выйдет - как определить в приведенном примере 2 и 3 текст это "test text2" + "test | [ textт 3" или же  "test text2 | test " + " [ textт 3". Вообще я бы сказал, что нужно экранировать управляющие символы на источнике текста.

Comment: Ну, вообще-то написал "при чем в "любой текст" могут быть и любые символы, такие как [ | ]" ))))
Хотелось бы, чтобы разделение кончалось на первом знаке, т.е. с таким результатом "test text2" + "test | [ textт 3"
Пока регулярочки помогают достичь желательного эффекта, но я не понял, как в ней указать, что мне нужны квадртаные скобки(

Comment: Скорее всего, через \\[

Comment: БИНГО! Только там почему то два слэша \\[. спасибо) вроде справлюсь дальше)
а понятно))) два слэша тут не отображается)))

Comment: Именно, я попытался вставить, как надо - с одним слэшем, потом понял, что слэш надо тут экранировать.